# Closed form of sum with binomial

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I want to find closed form of the following expression :

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried some small values of $n $ for inspiration?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-idenity-without-calculus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} &= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k x^{2k} \, dx
\end{align*}
and
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k x^{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-x^2)^k \, .
$$
Do you see how to finish this using the binomial theorem?  This will allow you to express the sum in terms of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I used beta function and its relation with Gamma function.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$ f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}.$$
Then calculate $f'(x)$ and I think you can do the rest.