# A proof of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{n}{i}\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+....+\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

How can I prove $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i-1}\dbinom{n}{i}\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+....+\frac{1}{n}\quad ?$$
I have tried induction, but it doesn't work.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-idenity-without-calculus

Comment: You can prove it by using definite integration. See my answer below.

Comment: Idea: Call the LHS $\sum_i f(i,n)$ for a moment. Consider $\sum_n\sum_i f(i,n)x^n$, switch the summation, and simplify. At the end of the simplification, find out what the coefficient of $x^n$ is. (Remember that $\sum_n\binom nix^n=\frac{x^i}{(x-1)^{i+1}}$.)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** You may consider
$$
I_n:=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx.
$$ On the one hand use

> $$
> \frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}=1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1},\qquad x\neq 1,
> $$

then integrate the finite sum  termwise.

On the other hand make the change of variable $t:=1-x$ giving

> $$
> \int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1-(1-t)^n}{t}dt
> $$

then expand the integrand by using the binomial theorem and integrate termwise.

Comment: I tried your second one by expand the binomial theorem and integrate termwise  but  I cannot get the same as mine.

Comment: @John You get $$ \frac{1-(1-t)^n}{t}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i-1}\dbinom{n}{i}t^{i-1}$$ then you just integrate each term using $\int_0^1t^{i-1}dt=\frac{1}{i}$.

Comment: Shouldn't $dt=-dx$

Comment: Hence shouldn't there be a minus sign in you last integral equality

Comment: @Albas In my answer or in my comment?

Comment: Yes @OliverOla in your last integral inequality where you substituted t=1-x. So $dt=-dx$

Comment: I think you are forgetting the bounds: $1 \to 0$ and $0 \to1$, so there is *no* minus sign to put.

Comment: Ahh..i did not notice the bounds . Sorry

Comment: @Albas You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Induction works fine, though you have to be a little clever at one point. For convenience I’ll use the standard notation

$$H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1n\;.$$

Now using the fact that $\frac1k\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac1n\binom{n}k$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{n+1}i\frac1i&\overset{(1)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac1i\left(\binom{n}i+\binom{n}{i-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac1i\binom{n}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac1i\binom{n}{i-1}\\
&\overset{(2)}=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\frac1i\binom{n}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac1{n+1}\binom{n+1}i\\
&\overset{(3)}=H_n+\frac1{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{n+1}i\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $(1)$ uses Pascal’s identity, $(2)$ uses the identity mentioned above, and $(3)$ uses the induction hypothesis. Thus,

$$\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{n+1}i=H_n\;,$$

and you can easily solve for $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac1i\binom{n+1}i$ to find that it is indeed $H_{n+1}$.