# Sum of Binomials Coefficients multiplied by the harmonic numbers

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I am interested in solve the next sum:

$\sum_{i=1}^{N} {N \choose i} i^{-G}$

for $G \geq 1$. Some ideas?

Thank you in advance by your help!

Comment: The solution for the case where $G=1$ is given in my solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1468503/168053).

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't give a closed form solution, but we can compute a generating function:
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{N\geq 0} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N {N\choose i}i^{-G}\right)x^N&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^{-G}\sum_{N=i}^{\infty} {N\choose i}x^N\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^{-G} \frac{x^i}{(1-x)^{i+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-x} \mathrm{Li}_G\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right),
\end{align*}
$$
where $\mathrm{Li}_G(t):=\sum_{n\geq 1} n^{-G} t^n$ is the polylogarithm.