# Can this be proved using definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

It's a problem from a high school math book that I've been unable to solve:

> Prove using definite integrals that,  $${n \choose 1}-\frac{1}{2}{n \choose 2}+\frac{1}{3}{n \choose 3}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}{n \choose n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}$$

I've tried using binomial expansions but to no avail. I cannot see any other approach to it using definite integrals. Although I am not sure if this is true. So, if one cannot prove it, can you please at least give me some numerical evidence of its correctness. A proof will be much better though.

Comment: Shouldn't the term $(-1)^{n-1}{n \choose n}$ on the l.h.s. be $(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}{n \choose n}$? Just asking, in case of a typo...

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo Yeah. I've edited it.

Comment: This question is not quite a duplicate of that other *question*, since this question says to use definite integrals and the other one doesn't, but the first *answer* to the other question is a duplicate since it does use definite integrals. Therefore I am voting to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand side is $$\int_0^11+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx$$
The left-hand side is a similar integral, with $x$ replaced by $1-x$.

Comment: how do you avoid the singularity?

Comment: There is none because the denominator divides into the numerator.  The other way, the denominator is $x$, and the constant term in the numerator is zero.

Comment: When you substitute $u=1-x$, you change the limits, so it is $-\int_1^0\frac{1-(1-u)^n}udu$.  Expand the numerator, and it looks a lot like your left-hand side.

Comment: Yeah... Now I see...