# Evaluate: $C_0+\frac{C_1}2+\frac{C_2}3+\cdots\frac{C_n}{n+1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations

Evaluate: $C_0+\frac{C_1}2+\frac{C_2}3+\cdots\frac{C_n}{n+1}$.Where $C_k$ denote the usual binomial coefficient.

MY TRY: I solved it and got $\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$,but it's ans. is given as $\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$.Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr x^r$$

$$\int_0^1(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr\int_0^1x^r$$

Comment: @MatheMagic, I would like to know your method, though!

Comment: Same as you did by integration but i forgot to put zero in LHS after integration.That's why i skipped 1.

Comment: @MatheMagic, Can you please try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-idenity-without-calculus  without the help of calculus

Answer (score 2):

$$\displaystyle\dfrac{\binom nr}{r+1}=\cdots=\dfrac{\binom{n+1}{r+1}}{n+1}$$

$$\displaystyle\implies\sum_{r=0}^n\dfrac{\binom nr}{r+1}=\dfrac1{n+1}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$
Now,
$$\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n+1}{r+1}=-\binom{n+1}0+\sum_{r=-1}^n\binom{n+1}{r+1}=-1+(1+1)^{n+1}$$