# Solving the Summation Cases

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}} {k} \binom{n} {k} = 1 +\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n}$

I and my friend discussed this two days ago. In this case, we prove that
it goes to $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k}$ (right-hand side expression in summation form), but unfortunately we went nothing. One thing that really evaporates the difficulty is when you need to apply the binomial expressions, related to summation lower bound and upper bound, to prove it, however I suspect that we may lack of knowledge knowing the identity/theorem which maybe useful to approach this problem. So, do you have any idea for this one?

Comment: Your equation can't possibly be right because for even $n$ the left hand side is negative. Did you mean $(-1)^{k-1}$?

Comment: Oh yeah, mistyped.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-identity-without-calculus

Comment: Induction should help if you want to prove it directly without using much else than elementary knowledge about the binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [a beautiful proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) of this identity from the integral representation:

$$H_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx$$

This is easy to confirm because:

$$\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} = 1 + x + \dots + x^{n-1}$$

Then,

\begin{align*}
H_n &= \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1-(1-u)^n}{u}du\\
 &= \int_0^1 \frac{1-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k (-u)^k}{u}du\\
 &= \int_0^1 \left(-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom n k  u^{k-1}\right)du\\
 &= -\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\binom n k\int_0^1   u^{k-1}du\\
 &= -\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\binom n k \frac{1}{k}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The following variation is *Example 3* in section 1.2  of John Riordan's classic *[Combinatorial Identities](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471722758)*.

> Consider for $n=1,2,\ldots$
>   \begin{align*}
> f_n&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\left[\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right]\frac{1}{k}\\
> &=f_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\\
> &=f_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\left[(1-1)^n-1\right]\\
> &=f_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}\\
> &=H_n
> \end{align*}
>   since $f_1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

We can use binomial expansion. Consider series:

$ (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}=(1-\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}=∑ ^n_{k=1} (-1)^{k-1}(\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}$

But;..$∑ ^n_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}=(1+1)^{n-1}=2^{n-1} =∑ ^n_{k=1}2^{k-1}$

Therefore term by term multiplication of series on RHS and series$∑ ^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{n}$ is:

$ ∑ ^n_{k=1} (-1)^{k-1}(\frac{1}{2})^{k-1} . 2^{k-1}\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k}= ∑ ^n_{k=1} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n \times\frac{1}{2^n}∑ ^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{n}=∑ ^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Shane Dizzy Sukardy, please see my answer