# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n}{k} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

> How can I prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n}{k} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}.$$

I tried an induction but couldn't prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n+1}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n}{k}.$$
 Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-identity-without-calculus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to verify the inductive step, recall that $\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}$. Therefore
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n+1}{k}&=
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n}{k-1}+
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n}{k}\\
&=
\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n+1}{k}+
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n}{k}\\
&=
\frac{1}{n+1}+
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \binom{n}{k}
\end{align}$$
where at the last step we used
$$1=1-(1-1)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n+1}{k}.$$

Comment: Yes! thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a well-known trick:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k\binom{n}k&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}k
\int_0^1 x^{k-1}\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{1-(1-x)^n}x\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\,dy=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_0^1 y^{k-1}\,dy
=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k.
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice trick +1

Comment: Very similar to this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2893244/108128