# Proving that $\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^k\over k+1}\binom{n}{k}={1\over n+1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I would like if possible to have a proof of yet another theorem of Binomial Coefficients. This time it is $$\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^k\over k+1}\binom{n}{k}={1\over n+1}$$

This arises in a proof of the theorem to the effect that $$\operatorname{\Gamma}(n,\mu)$$ is equal to the hypervolume cut out of the positive unit hyperbox with one corner at the origin and each edge parallel to an axis by the hypersurface defined by $$\prod_{k=1}^n x_k=e^{-\mu} .$$

Again, because I did find a proof of the this theorem *other than* by the route inwhich this theorem of *binomial coefficients* arose, I now *do effectively* have a proof of this theorem of binomial coefficients ... but again, taken as a proof *per se* it's absurdly complex; and I think *there must be* an elementary one: and besides, as I have said elsewhere, I like to have an *entire map* of a mathematical 'landscape' rather than just knowledge of a particular 'route' connecting this place & that.

I was shown two *excellent* proofs for the theorem of *binomial coefficients & Pochhammer numbers* that I requested a proof of; bur I don't think these are applicable to this one - not unadapted in someway anyhow - and possibly a proof by a completely different route would serve better in this case.

Comment: Do you mean $(-1)^k$ rather than $(-1)^n$ in the sum?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-identity-without-calculus

Comment: @user10354138 -- I definitely _did_ mean that - thankyou!

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee -- Ah some tougher ones! I'm neglectful of studying things like that - which is why I have occasion to keep asking for these elementary proofs. Thx for that link.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac1{n+1}
$$
instead of
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac1{n+1},
$$
(which doesn't make any sense when $n$ is odd, the LHS is negative due to the $(-1)^n$ but the RHS is positive) then one obvious way is just integrating
$$
(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^k
$$
term-by-term between $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Comment: It's you again! Yes - that looks like a proof to me. Simpler than the proof of the other I asked for a proof of. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^k\over k+1}\binom{n}{k}=
\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^k\over n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}=
\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^k}\binom{n+1}{k+1}=
\frac{1}{n+1}[(1-1)^{n+1} + 1] = \frac{1}{n+1}.
$$

Comment: That's a truly different method than that of the other answer! ... so I'm well- pleased with this result. Thanks mightily for your contribution also. Hopefully, once I've seen a few of these I'll have the _kind_ of method securely installed, & shan't _need_ to ask for these proofs, which I see _in retrospect_ are actually quite elementary. ¶ I'd just like to mention votes - I don't think much of the idea of having to choose only one answer - so I'm not going to use the system _atall_ ... & besides, in _this_ case, as I said, the proofs are by two different methods _anyway_!