# A question on binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If $C_0$, $C_1$, $C_2$,...$C_n$ are the coefficients in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer, show that $$C_1- {C_2\over 2}
+{C_3\over 3}-...+{(-1)^{n-1} C_n\over n}=1+ {1\over 2}+ {1\over 3}+...+{1\over n}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-identity-without-calculus

Answer (score 3):

Evaluate
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-(1-x)^n}xdx$$
in two different ways.

**First way:** 
$$1-(1-x)^n=1-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nkx^k=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom nkx^k$$
so
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-(1-x)^n}xdx=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom nk\int_0^1x^{k-1}dx=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom nk\frac1k$$
$$=\frac{\binom n1}1-\frac{\binom n2}2+\frac{\binom n3}3-\cdots+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\binom nn}n.$$

**Second way:** Substituting $u=1-x$,
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-(1-x)^n}xdx=\int_0^1\frac{1-u^n}{1-u}du=\int_0^1(1+u+u^2+\cdots+u^{n-1})du$$$$=\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you are saying that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k} \dbinom{n}{k} = \dfrac{1}{1} + \dfrac{1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n}
\end{equation}
(because your $C_k$ are precisely the binomial coefficients $\dbinom{n}{k}$).

This is a fairly known identity. The one place I remember seeing a proof (because I wrote it) is Exercise 3.19 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10th of January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10). I suspect it's been on math.stackexchange a few times already.

(If you're looking for a hint: Induction on $n$.)