# Binomial sum having positive and negative terms

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Find $\displaystyle \binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{4}+\binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{7}+\cdots \cdots $

What I tried:

the sum is $$\sum^{n}_{r=0}(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{3r+1}$$

$$\sum^{n}_{r=0}(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}\int^{1}_{0}x^{3r}dx$$

$$\int^{1}_{0}\sum^{n}_{r=0}(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}x^{3r}dx$$

How do I solve?  Help me, please!

Comment: Why is the sum taken from $0$ to $\infty$? Shouldn't it be from $0$ to $n$? Also, shouldn't the fractions be $1/(3r+1)$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-identity-without-calculus

Comment: i saw a question like this once and it had something to do with the binomial expansion of $(1+\omega)^n$ where $\omega$ is a complex number on the unit circle

Comment: @Seth, this uses binomial expansion, but is not complex at all.

Answer (score 4):

As Zubin Mukerjee commented, the sum should be from $0$ to $n$ (as $\tbinom n {n+k}=0$ for $k>0$), and the fraction is an expression in terms of the iterator, $r$.

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^r\binom nr}{3r+1}\quad=\quad\int_0^1\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\binom nr x^{3r}~\mathsf d x$$

Up next, the Binomial Expansion Theorem says: $$(1+a)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n a^r\binom nr$$

Take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Melzak's identity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07006) $$\sum_{k=0}^{j}\dbinom{j}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{f\left(y-k\right)}{k+x}=\frac{f\left(x+y\right)}{x\dbinom{j+x}{j}}$$ where $f$ is an algebraic polynomial up to degree $j$ and $x\neq-k$ we get, taking $f\left(y\right)\equiv1$ and $x=1/a,\,a>0$, that $$\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=0}^{j}\dbinom{j}{k}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k+1/a}=\color{red}{\dbinom{j+1/a}{j}^{-1}}.$$ In your case, $a=3.$