# $ \text{why} -\int_{0}^{1}{({1 - t})^{n} - 1 \over t}d t = \int_{0}^{1}{t^{n} - 1 \over t - 1}d t ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Question link : [Proving Binomial Identity without calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523/proving-binomial-identity-without-calculus)

i have  one  doubt  in the  given answer below ,my doubts mark in red colour
[image]

My doubt is that  $$ \text{why} -\int_{0}^{1}{({1 - t})^{n} - 1 \over t}d t =
\int_{0}^{1}{t^{n} - 1 \over t - 1}d t ?$$

My attempt : Take $n= 2$ then ${({1 - t})^{n} - 1 \over t} \neq {t^{n} - 1 \over t - 1}$

that is $-\int_{0}^{1}{({1 - t})^{n} - 1 \over t}d t \neq
\int_{0}^{1}{t^{n} - 1 \over t - 1}d t $

I don't understand  where im  doing mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $u=1-t$ to get

$$\int_{0}^{1}{({1 - t})^{n} - 1 \over t}d t 
= \int_{0}^{1}{u^{n} - 1 \over u- 1}d u
$$

Comment: You dropped a minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

Use a $u$-substitution with $u=1-t$ and then change $u$ to $t$.